# How many servers & what equipment needed to start a file storage/Backup service?

Tags: backup, cloud, storage, amazon-cloudfront, remote-backup

I want to start my own file storage/backup service like Dropbox, Skydrive, Box etc. I have 60000 customers. I want to give each customer 1GB free space (lifetime). That means I need 60TB of storage. I will increase space for more users time to time. I want my file backup service to be cloud based, redundancy. Can you please tell me how many servers & how powerful servers it's needed? Also, what equipment, accessories it's needed to make a powerful service? From where I can buy them with best price? Please tell me. Also, if you have other information regarding file backup/storage service, it will be helpful for me please. Also feel free to ask me :)

Comment: I guess you don't want redundancy? What if one server goes down...don't you need to have the data in at least 2 locations????

Comment: Yes, I want redundancy :) I forgot to describe it. @SQLMenace

Comment: That means I need more 60TB storage? @SQLMenace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build your own service on top of Amazon's cloud infrastructure. See this: http://aws.amazon.com/backup-storage/

Comment: Is it possible to start my service with Glacier plan? Does it(Glacier) support redundancy? What is the price for 60TB with redundancy? I am Not sure about bandwidth (ignorant about it :). Or, how much it will cost per month or year for 20TB or 60TB with bandwidth cost to start my service. Please tell me. I am not sure about total pricing with Storage, Request, Data transfer

Comment: You can check the prices for each service, which are typically based on usage and instance size. But you can always hire a Cloud Solutions Architect to work up a design for you.